# Potential of a couple with non-angular lagrangian coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring

In the following system, the disc is vinculated to move along the y axis and the point P to move along the x axis. There is no friction. I need to determine the potential energy so that I can later apply the Lagrangian formalism. The lagrangian coordinates are x and y as depicted in the figure. In the provided  solutions they give directly the following expresion for the potential:

[image]
[image]

I don't know how they determined the potential corresponding to the anti-clockwise couple M: $ -M\frac{y}{R}$ Normally, I have only see examples in which there was some angular lagrangian coordinate $\theta$, for which the potential energy was pretty straightforward: $M\theta$ . Since in this problem there is no angular lagrangian coordinate, I can't use that. How do I go about it?

Comment: well I can post a solution but I want you to notice two things first you may not need the solution after this : 1) work done my couples and torques are just equal to $\int M d\theta\;$ 2) as the disk moves down a distance $y$ you can see that $ \theta = \frac{y}{R}$

Comment: @Aditya Garg Thanks I see it , but something is bugging me,  how do I know the $\theta$ of the integral is the same $\theta$ as in the rolling condition?

Comment: @mathlover what else could it be ?